# Как установить зависимость в Intelij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, зависимости, модули

Как в модуле установить зависимость от com.intellij:annotations:12.0.
Пользуюсь Intellij Idea(Собираю Java проект на Gradle).
В google ничего внятного не нашел

Comment: compile group: 'com.intellij', name: 'annotations', version: '12.0' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное любую зависимость можно найти [тут](https://mvnrepository.com/)
Просто в поиске к примеру пишем com.intellij:annotations, увидим подходящий вариант, выбираем версию, и переходим на нужную нам вкладку - Maven\Gradle\SBT и т.д.